# sudo command over php ssh2

Tags: php, ssh, sudo

I have a user with sysadm rights, and can login as root by using `sudo su -`, which is nopasswd set in etc/sudoers.

Now, I am trying to execute a sudo command from php, running from WAMPserver on windows. 
I've tried using `ssh2_exec()`, `exec()` of phpseclib, but the commands return no output.

My ssh2 connect function uses the same user with sysadm rights.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: to achieve what? why would you want to change the user php is running as in such a way?

Comment: I want to get the output of a sudo command through this. I do not want to change the way the user is running .